# Openbravo ERP Source code link

Tags: openbravo

I am doing setup for Openbravo in my local machine . I want java source code link for same . Can any one tell me the source code link for Openbravo ERP .

Comment: Refer this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55255716/how-to-get-the-latest-openbravo-erp-to-work-unable-to-find-a-starting-point

Answer (score 0):

The source code:
https://code.openbravo.com/erp/devel/main/file/21d052f37ed3

Installation Guide:
http://wiki.openbravo.com/wiki/Installation/Custom/Mercurial_Clone