# How to get the latest Openbravo ERP to work? Unable to find a starting point

Tags: openbravo

**Introduction** I've been searching for a while now, but unable to find proper support for community edition of OpenBravo. The wiki is present but seems to be outdated, having pages updated in 2018 linking to old pages dated 2011 that seem to irrelevant now, missing downloads etc.

The page
http://wiki.openbravo.com/wiki/Installation/Appliance/ISO
refers to a download page having **openbravo-3.0PR18Q4.2-amd64.iso**.
This page is dated November 2018 and states that the version of this ISO will be available in two months (at the time of writing this question 4 months have passed.)

The download link is
http://www.openbravo.com/content/download-openbravo-3-community-edition which redirects to http://www.openbravo.com/community/
and this page doesn't have any downloads.

Also on this **Community** page, at the bottom if we want to get information http://forums.openbravo.com
this link shows an **Forbidden** error, and I can't find a way to signup if any account is needed.

Though I was able to download the ISO from
https://sourceforge.net/projects/openbravo/files/01-openbravo-appliances/3.0PR18Q3.5/
But this seems to be an old version, while running it over VMWare player, I'm unable find any signs of pre-installed dependencies needed for **OpenBravo**.

Now my goal is to make it from source. The repository location I've found it https://code.openbravo.com/erp/stable and the latest date I see here is from 2015. Please do mention if you happen to know where the latest repository is.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use http://wiki.openbravo.com/wiki/Installation/Custom to setup the instance.

Here http://code.openbravo.com/erp/devel/main latest version can be found.

Answer (score 0):

Download source https://gitlab.com/openbravo/product/openbravo
Example 21Q1 version https://gitlab.com/openbravo/product/openbravo/-/tree/release/21Q1

Follow the Openbravo Wiki for installation.

http://wiki.openbravo.com/wiki/Installation/Custom

If you need further support message me.

Answer (score 0):

Download Docker

## docker pull rotemsecupi/ubuntu1204-openbravo-new

Start Docker with Ubuntu 12/04 LTR
#docker run -d -p 80:80 rotemsecupi/ubuntu1204-openbravo-new

http://localhost/openbravo
Username: Openbravo
Password: openbravo

Contact for Detail:
Openbravo.com@gmail.com
https://facebook.com/openbravo